# Copying ConcurrentHashMap to HashMap inconsistency

Tags: java, multithreading, copy, concurrenthashmap, atomicinteger

im trying to do the following:

1. My program starts threads, which increment an `AtomicInteger` from `ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>` and adds new `Integer` to `ConcurrentHashMap<String, CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer>>`. In that case, the size of the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is equal to the Value of the `AtomicInteger` (of course for entries with the same key)
2. After all threads are done (when the `CountDownLatch` is finished) I try to convert `ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>` into `HashMap<String, Integer>` for sorting that Map by Value, because `AtomicInteger` is not comparable.
3. After conversion I sort the `HashMap` by the Values and pick 20 entries with the highest value - in the sorted Map they are the first 20 entries.
4. Finally I pack the Values in an List and make JSON String with GSON.

**Issue**

What I expect: due my usage of `AtomicInteger`, `ConcurrentHashMap` and `CopyOnWriteArrayList`  I expect that all sizes and values for all entries with the same key are equal, even in my JSON String like:

```
myAtomcIntegerConcurrentHashMap.get("ABC").intValue() == 
myCOWArrayListConcurrentHashMap.get("ABC").size() == 
myNewHashMap.get("ABC")
```

But result seems be different. I made some console outputs to test my Values and got the following:

While copying from `ConcurrentHashMap` to `HashMap` I verify my values again. Every time the "bad copied" values are different (for the code snippet look below):

```
 COWArrayList.size  AtomicInteger.intValue  Value in new HashMap
 299                299                     298
 122                122                     121
```

After that I iterate 4 more times over my new `HashMap` to compare my values again and every time I get new random "bad copied" values (notice, the values were not detected while copying) (for the code snippet look below):

```
 COWArrayList.size  AtomicInteger.intValue  Value in new HashMap  Common Key
 849                849                     827                   CGCCACC
 838                838                     813                   GGTGGTG
```

My Json is also incorrect. E.g. for the Key `"CGCCACC"` Size of my Array in Json is `887`, not like in the Table above (`849`).

**Here are code snippets I use** (Some of them are from StackOverflow):

Incrementing `AtomicInteger` and adding new Integer to `CopyOnWriteArrayList` in my Threads:

```java
//Add new Integer 'position' to the COWArrayList from 'positions' with the key 'frame'
List<Integer> copyArr = positions.get(frame);
if (copyArr == null) {
  copyArr = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer>();
  List<Integer> inMap = positions.putIfAbsent(frame, (CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer>) copyArr);
  if (inMap != null) copyArr = inMap; // already in map
}
copyArr.add(position);

//Increment the AtomicInteger from 'scores' with the key 'frame'
AtomicInteger value = scores.get(frame);
if (value==null){ 
  value = new AtomicInteger();
  AtomicInteger actual = scores.putIfAbsent(frame, value);
  if(actual != null) value = actual;
}
value.incrementAndGet();
```

Copy from `ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>` to the `HashMap<String, Integer>` each value (I guess its very inefficient) and immediate verifying:

```java
//init new, non-concurrent Map
Map<String, Integer> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

//iterate over the Map and copy each value from 'scores' to 'newHashMap'
for(Map.Entry<String, AtomicInteger> score : scores.entrySet()){
  myHashMap.put(score.getKey(), score.getValue().intValue());

  //verify just added Value and print values of all Maps if something is wrong
  if(score.getValue().intValue() != myHashMap.get(score.getKey())){
    System.out.println(score.getValue().intValue() + " " + positions.get(score.getKey()).size() + " " + myHashMap.get(score.getKey()));
  }
}
```

Verifying copied values of `myHashMap` again (here I also get random "bad copied" values):

```java
for(Map.Entry<String, AtomicInteger> score : scores.entrySet()){
  if(score.getValue().intValue() != myHashMap.get(score.getKey())){
  System.out.println(score.getValue().intValue() + " = " + positions.get(score.getKey()).size() + " =? " + myHashMap.get(score.getKey()));
  }
}
```

Why could that happen, have I missed something in my logic?

For further information / code etc. - just ask.

**Thank you for helping me!**

Comment: The iterator of a `ConcurrentHashMap` is weakly consistent; they may, or may not, reflect content changes of the underlying collection. This  may be why you have problems.

Comment: a succession of atomic instructions is not atomic.

Comment: A friendly suggestion: dump your posh lock-free code and use plain old locks. You'll be surprised how well that can perform.

Comment: @UmNyobe: in which part of my code? Data, produced by Threads is ok, the copying fails.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I used to have the locks before, but the performance of my threads goes then to the ground. On 32 Core machine it takes only ~30% of the all power; With lock-free code all cores are powered to 100%.

Comment: Why do you need separate maps for `List`s and `AtomicInteger`s? Cannot you use only `List`s?

Comment: Have you made sure that all threads are finished before you start copying to the HashMap?

Comment: @StevenPessall to check, if all Threads done I use CoutnDownLatch (myLatch.await()) then I make all that iterations.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `AtomicInteger` ques by calling `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()` an increment event. My threads are calling that function ~3.5 Mio times and the Queue is huge. After my Threads are done, the main Thread instantly copies the `ConcurrentHashMap` of `AtomicInteger`, but the queue of some `AtomicIntegers` is not completley done. That makes the inconsistency.

I solved that by giving the `AtomicInteger` some time to finish it "increment Queue" after all threads are done.

```java
    try {
        myCountDownLatch.await();
        Thread.sleep(5000); //let AtomicInteger finish they incrementations
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error in a Latch Countdown: " + e.toString());
    }
```

**And voila! There no inconsistency anymore!**

If there is another method to wait for `AtomicInteger` finish their increment Queues, I would be thankful to read about that.

Comment: That is only part of the story, if your CountDownLatch is properly initialized with proper number of threads to wait for, there should't be any pending increases in AtomicIntegers after the latch is opened, check that if you are waiting for proper number of threads to finish.